# bootstrap navbar not making itself sticky without fixed width

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, sticky-footer, navbar

I have a twitter-bootstrap navbar in the middle of some content and I would like to make it sticky.

I am using the [sticky jquery plugin](http://stickyjs.com/), [github page](https://github.com/garand/sticky).

As it says in the github page itself:

> In some cases you might need to set a fixed width to your element when it is "sticked"

I've experimented with this and:

- [Here is a **non working** example without a fixed width](http://jsfiddle.net/Trufa/APdyT/4/).
- [Here is a **working** example with a fixed width](http://jsfiddle.net/Trufa/APdyT/5/).

The only difference lies here:

```
width:20px;
```

The problem is that I can't make it work for my navbar that when scrolled just jumps to a smaller width and stays in place.

See the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Trufa/APdyT/3/).

No now I'm conflicted as to how to solve the problem since I am happy the way the navbar is looking, would adding a fixed width break the twitter-bootstrap functionality?

The other problem is that even when adding a fixed width, it doesn't become sticky either.

[Here is the example](http://jsfiddle.net/Trufa/APdyT/7/) where I have added:

```
#stickynavbar{
    width:200px;
}
```

So the question I have is either:

- How to solve this particular problem or
- Since it is very early in the projects life, maybe another plugin or a solution outside the box will serve me just as good.

Whatever pointers in the right direction, solving this particular problem or avoiding them by using a completely different approach will do.

Comment: I have good expirience with this plugin http://someweblog.com/demo/hcsticky/

Comment: It does work for a common div, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Trufa/APdyT/13/) but it doesn't work for the navbar either for some reason, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Trufa/APdyT/15/).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/APdyT/16/

Comment: You must put whole navbar inside div with stickynavbar id :)

Comment: @MiljanPuzović awesome, it works, if you make an answer out the the comment I will accept it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid fixing code, i recommend [hcSticky](http://someweblog.com/hcsticky-jquery-floating-sticky-plugin/) jQuery plugin.

Implementation is easy: `$('selector').hcSticky();`

After implementing this plugin, your code looks like [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/APdyT/16/).

Answer (score 0):

`width: 100%` for `#stickynavbar`?